# Count <tr> from html string without using HtmlDoc

Tags: c#, html

I want to count the number of rows in html string returned from API. Any idea to get the rows count without using html agility pack ?

following code will connect to API and return html string for apiContent.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    var response = client.GetAsync(apiURL).Result;
    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
    {
        Task<string> result = content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        apiContent = result.Result;
    }
}
```

now i need to count the numbers of row (tr) from html string in variable "apiContent" but without using html agility pack.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What about RegEx?

Comment: What if there are nested rows? You want to count them to or only the top level?

Comment: @andyb952 Are you suggesting to parse some HTML with a Regex?

Comment: @aloisdg Yeah why not?

Comment: @andyb952 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1248177

Comment: thanks. never think about regex just now. now i get the rowcount with just one row  of code : Regex.Matches(apiContent, @"<tr>.*<\/tr>").Count. :)

Comment: @Yanly be careful with regex. Take the time to read both links above.

Answer (score 1):

If the only `<TR>`'s being returned are what you are interested in, why not just do a LINQ `.Count()`?

```
int count = result.Count(f => f == '<tr');
```

Comment: What if you have some commented `<tr`?

Comment: If the commenting follows a standard format, just do `f => f == '<tr' && f!= '<!-- <tr'` or whatever your case may be.  If it's not in any standard format, good luck.

Comment: what if your html includes something like `<script>var a='<trace>';</script>`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a robust solution without HtmlAgilityPack.

Lets consider this HTML:

```
var html = "<table><tr><td>cell</td></tr><!--<tr><td>comment</td></tr>--></table>"
```

Lets load this HTML as a document:

```
// Create a new context for evaluating webpages with the default configuration
var context = BrowsingContext.New(Configuration.Default);
// Parse the document from the content of a response to a virtual request
var document = await context.OpenAsync(req => req.Content(html));
```

Query whatever you are looking for in your HTML:

```
var rows = document.QuerySelectorAll("tr");
Console.WriteLine(rows.Count());
```

[Try it online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fYXh8a)

Whenever you want to parse HTML, always rely on a HTML parser. If you dont want to use HAP, [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp) is a great alternative. If you dont want to use an existing HTML parser, you are doomed to make your own. It will be easier on a subset of HTML, but mostly not worth the hassle. Help yourself ; use a library.